# LLVM constant in DAG changes when lowering

Tags: llvm

`%bf.clear = and i8 %bf.load, -32`

`-view-dag-combine1-dags`

[image]

`-view-legalize-dags`

[image]

How can i prevent this change? (-32 is correct).

Answer (score 0):

It's a perfectly legal transformation. If `i8` is not a legal type for your target, then legalizer promotes `i8` to `i32`. The `-32` constant is legalized to 224, as upper bits clearly should not matter (and influence the result).

So, if this is a problem, then I'd suppose that there is some problem elsewhere.